# Как корректно записать/считать в/из файла структуру с полями типа string?

Tags: c++, строки, структуры

Имеется структура

```
struct User {
    string login;
    string password;
};
```

Стоит задача сделать примитивную авторизация пользователя. Т.е. создается файлик, в него записывается заполненный объект вышеуказанной структуры, а при последующих запусках производится запрос логина+пароля, считываются данные из файлика и сравниваются. Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct User {
    string login;
    string password;
};

void main ()
{
    SetConsoleCP (1251); // установка универсальной кодировки
    SetConsoleOutputCP (1251);

    string path;
    int realsize=0;
    User u;
    vector <User> U;
    bool exit = false;

    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Укажите, на каком диске находится файл с регистрационными данными:\n";
        getline(cin, path);
        path += ":\\users.txt";
        ifstream fin(path, ios_base::binary | ios_base::in);

        if (fin.is_open())
        {
            cout<<"Отлично, ваш файл найден!\n";
            fin.read((char*)&u, sizeof(User));
            U.push_back(u);
            fin.close();
            cout << "Введите логин:\n";
            getline(cin, u.login);
            cout << "Введите пароль:\n";
            getline(cin, u.password);
            if (!U.at(0).login.compare(u.login) && !U.at(0).password.compare(u.password))
            {
                cout << "Вы авторизованы!\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Вы не авторизованы!\n";
            }
            exit = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Файл не найден и будет создан";
            ofstream fout (path, ios_base::binary | ios_base::out);
            if (fout.is_open())
            {
                cout << "Введите логин:\n";
                getline(cin, u.login);
                cout << "Введите пароль:\n";
                getline(cin, u.password);
                fout.write((char*)&u, sizeof(User));
                fout.close();
                cout << "Файл создан и данные внесены!\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Ошибка при создании файла! Работа приложения будет завершена.\n";
                exit = true;
            }
        }
    } while(!exit);

    system("pause");

}
```

Вся беда в том, что при выполнении данного кода появляется ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x0FDECCC8 (msvcp110.dll) в test.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x0067ADE4.

Кадры стека вызовов:

[image: стек вызовов]

Путем экспериментов установлено, что замена использования вектора на простой динамический массив никак не влияет на ошибку (т.е. она по-прежнему появляется), а вот замена использования `string` на `char *` приводит к устранению проявления данной ошибки. Погуглив, я пришел в выводу, что возникает какая-то ошибка в деструкторе `string` (могу ошибаться). Может кто-нибудь прояснить ситуацию и дать рекомендации по корректному использованию типа `string` в данного рода задачах?

Comment: А зачем вы файл открываете как бинарный и читаете строку? Попробуйте убрать флаги в методе .open(path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ (как уже упомянул в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559966/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-string#comment727238_559966) @pavel) - использовать текстовый режим работы с файлом и операторы форматированного ввода/вывода ([`operator<<`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3C%3C/), [`operator>>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3E%3E/)) для чтения/записи `std::string` из/в потока.

Чтение:

```
ifstream fin(path); 
if (fin) {
   fin >> u.login >> u.password;
}
```

Запись:

```
ofstream fout(path); 
if (fout) {
   // Разделители нужны для последующего считывания
   fout << u.login << " " << u.password << "\n"; 
}
```

При этом данный подход накладывает некоторые ограничения на строки: как минимум они не должны содержать в себе символы пробельной группы, т.к. такой символ будет расценен как разделитель.

Функции [`istream::read`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/), [`ostream::write`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) в этом случае не используются вовсе. Причина, по которой они не работают как надо указана в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559976/176217) @gbg.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian об этом уже написано :) Главное, идея, а как разделить данные это уже частности.

Comment: Да кто же до конца то читает ответы )

Comment: @VladimirGamalian будем надеяться, что хотя бы ТС прочтет :)

Comment: @alexolut прочту, конечно :) спасибо за развернутые пояснения и корректный ответ, но первым был Vladimir Gamalian :)

Comment: @LivAlex справедливости ради, проверьте временную отметку ответов :)

Comment: @alexolut прошу прощения, не сразу заметил, что ранние ответы ниже. Исправился.

Comment: @LivAlex выбирайте ответ, который Вам больше подходит, а не по признаку первичности. А способ сортировки ответов можно менять. Есть варианты "Текущие", "Старые", "Голоса".

Answer (score 2):

Запись в файл с помощью

```
fout.write((char*)&u, sizeof(User));
```

действительно запишет побайтово содержимое структуры User, но т.к. она содержит не POD типы (`std::string`), то пользы от этого мало, т.к. сами данные ваших строк скорей всего в куче находятся.

В вашем случае можно записать логин и пароль в файл (при условии, что в них не используется перевод строки), по одному на строчку, и также читать. Пример:

```
int main() {
    struct User {
        std::string login;
        std::string password;
    };

    {
        User user{ "login", "password" };

        // Пишем логин и пароль в файл в две строчки
        std::ofstream f("users.txt");
        f << user.login << std::endl << user.password;
    }

    {
        User user;

        // Читаем из файла
        std::ifstream f("users.txt");
        std::getline(f, user.login);
        std::getline(f, user.password);

        std::cout << user.login << std::endl << user.password << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Так работать не будет. `string` не является POD - типом, то есть сам объект типа `string` не содержит данные строки, они размещаются в другом месте (куда их затолкает аллокатор).

Правило простое - все, что не является POD нельзя просто так взять и скопировать побайтно.

Решение - использовать для хранения данных типы, являющиеся POD

```
struct mu_ugly_pod
{
    char user_name[100500];
    char user_last_name[100500];
};
```

Такая штуковина должна писаться и читаться без проблем. Увы, все удобства, связанные со `string` в данном случае пропадут.

Comment: спасибо за пояснения, этот способ я пробовал, он действительно рабочий, но я думал, что должен быть способ сохранить удобство использования типа string и выполнить задачу. *Пошел углублять познания по POD

Comment: @LivAlex это нужно велосипедить свою обертку с сериализацией. Что в итоге грозит потерей скорости. Если скорость критична для вас - лучше всего устроить отображение файла в память и string_range