# Ошибка при чтении символов из строки C++

Tags: visual-c++

Заливаю объект класса `Example` в файл с помощью `file.write`, после чего пытаюсь вылить его в другой объект с помощью `file.read`.

Code(заливаю в файл объект):

```
ofstream file("mytxt.txt", ofstream::app);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Example* Pups = new Example();
    Pups->age = "Возраст строкой, ДА-ДА";
    file.write((char*)& Pups, sizeof(Example));
    MyWonderfulVector.push_back(*Pups);
}
file.close();
```

Code(Выливаю объект с файла):

```
    ifstream file1;
Example Pups1;
file1.open("mytxt.txt", ios_base::in);
while(file1.read((char*)& Pups1, sizeof(Example))){
    Pups1.Print();

}
file1.close();
```

При считывании объекта из файла его свойство `string age` не читается, и внутри `age` оказывается:
<Ошибка при чтении символов строки>

Как мне это исправить? Спасите!
Сам класс Example:

```
class Example {
public:
    Example() {
        string age = "Привет";
    }
    string age;
    string Print() {
        return age;
    }


};
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/650106/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-string-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%A1

Comment: Что за чушь в классе? Зачем в конструкторе объявляется локальный `age`???

Comment: @AnT ну.. это значение по умолчанию

Comment: @AnT ну, я уже понял свою ошибку по поводу локального age)
Теперь бы с записью разобраться)

Comment: @AnT подскажите, что я сделал не так здесь:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980142/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, вот это

```
file.write((char*)& Pups, sizeof(Example));
```

не записывет никакой "объект класса Example", а записывет содержимое указателя `Pups`, да еще и с размером `sizeof(Example)`. Что уже само по себе является полнейшей чепухой.

Затем вы пытаетесь читать эти записанные указатели, как объекты типа `Example`. Ничего осмысленного из этого не выйдет.

Во-вторых, класс `Example` с полями типа `std::string` вообще в принципе нельзя так записывать. См.
[Как корректно записать/считать в/из файла структуру с полями типа string?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559966/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-string)
[Запись string в бинарый файл . С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/650106/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-string-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%A1)

Comment: А как мне записывать объект? Я гуглил, говорили, что так.

Comment: @justlead: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559966/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-string и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/650106/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-string-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%A1

Comment: А можете показать на моем примере, пожалуйста?

Comment: Я попробовал сделать как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/650106/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-string-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%A1

Comment: попробовал сделать как Вы показали(2ая ссылка)
Но у меня проблемка.
Записывает все верно, а читает из файла неправильно.
Записывает:
Name = "Петя"
Age = 5
Читает:
Name = ""
Age = 0