# Запись и чтение объекта из бинарного файла

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>   
using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

class foo
{
public:
    string Name = "Баби";
    int Age = 5;

    void show()
    {
        cout << "Name = " << Name << endl;
        cout << "Age = " << Age << endl;
    }

    void write(ostream& os) const
    {
        os.write((const char*)& Age, sizeof Age);

        size_t len = Name.length();
        os.write((const char*)& len, sizeof len);
        os.write(Name.c_str(), len);
    }

    void read(istream& in)
    {
        in.read((char*)& Age, sizeof Age);

        size_t len;
        in.read((char*)& len, sizeof len);
        Name.resize(len);
        in.read(&Name[0], len);
    }
};



int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    foo* obj = new foo();
    obj->Age = 5;
    obj->Name = "Масло";

    ofstream file("file.bin", ios::binary | ios::app);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        obj->write(file);
        obj->show();
    }
    file.close();

    foo* result = new foo();
    ifstream file1("file.bin", ios::binary);
    if (file1.is_open()) {
        result->read(file1);
        file1.close();
        result->show();
    }
    file1.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Неправильно записывает и читает из файла.
Записывает `age = 5`и `Name = "Масло"`, а выводит `age=0` и `Name = ""`.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @AnT До сих пор не могу решить проблему.
Изменил немного код, проблема остается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл не забывайте закрывать. Перед тем как пытаться открывать файл на чтение, надо не забывать закрыть предыдущее открытие (на запись). И не забывайте проверять, успешно ли вы у вас открылся файл - тогда бы вы сами поняли, почему "не работает" чтение.

Запись/чтение у вас сделано не так эффективно как могло бы, но тем не менее все правильно.

---

Более эффективно:

1. Если вы записываете длину строки, то записывать вместе со строкой ее нулевой символ не обязательно.
2. При чтении строки ее можно аккуратно прочитать прямо внутрь `std::string`, без создания промежуточного буфера

Например

```
void write(ostream& os) const
{
  os.write((const char*) &Age, sizeof Age);

  size_t len = Name.length();
  os.write((const char*) &len, sizeof len);
  os.write(Name.c_str(), len);
}

void read(istream& in)
{
  in.read((char*) &Age, sizeof Age);

  size_t len;                       
  in.read((char*) &len, sizeof len);
  Name.resize(len);
  in.read(Name.data(), len); // или `in.read(&Name[0], len);`
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Но у меня в строке `in.read(Name.data(), len);` пишет
`Аргумент типа const char* не совместим с типом char*`
Я так понимаю, это связано с тем, что `Name` это здесь const char*,а как его переводить в char*?

Comment: @justlead: Не `Name`, а `Name.data()`. Какой компилятор вы используете? Здесь нужен С++17. Если вы получаете такую ошибку, то замените эту строчку на `in.read(&Name[0], len);`

Comment: Запись в файл переменных типа size_t и int приведет к веселым багам при смене разрядности. Надо бы конвертировать в типы с фиксированной битовой шириной.

Comment: @gbg: Особенности мира бинарных файлов. Любой бинарный файл разрабатывается под конкретный набор требований времени жизни/переносимости: внутри сессии выполнения, между сессиями выполнения, между версиями программы, между программами данной С++ платформы, между платформами и т.п. У каждого варианта - свой набор требований.

Comment: Ну уж нет, это проявление недальновидности. Достаточно было использовать фиксированный формат, чтобы получить переносимую программу. А так получили потенциальные и очень дорогие проблемы.

Comment: @GB а как тогда следует делать?

Comment: @AnT сделал как Вы показали, но проблема сохраняется :(

Comment: @justlead: Вы что-то недоговариваете. Мне отсюда не видно. что у вас там творится.

Comment: @AnT, я изменил код в вопросе

Comment: @gbg: Это примерно как утверждать, что Windows должна свой своп-файл записывать в формате XML, а то получается "непереносимо и недальновидно". Еще раз: переносимость переносимости рознь и говорить о переносимости имеет смысл только для файлов, которые предназначены для переноса.

Comment: @justlead: О какой именно "проблеме" вы говорите? Код прекрасно компилирутеся. Запустил - работает. (Однако теперь вы переборщили с закрытиями файлов - лишних понаставили.)

Comment: @AnT записывает правильно, но читает неверно.
После чтение Age = 0, Name = "".
какие лишние?

Comment: Вы не состоянии самостоятельно разглядеть, что `file1` у вас закрывается два раза? Что касается записи/чтения, то может у вас какие проблемы с локализацией? Попробуйте на английском тексте для начала. Хотя как вы умудряетесь получать `Age=0` мне не ясно. У меня все работает. Мне кажется, что вы что-то выдумываете. Вы уверены, что запускаете именно приведенный код?

Comment: @AnT, попробуйте запустить мой код из вопроса, если не верите мне.
Про `file1` разглядел. Я компилиирую в визуалке 2019.

Comment: @AnT, а где вы запускаете?

Comment: @justlead: VS2017 и VS2019 - все прекрасно работает.

Comment: @AnT, очень странно..

Comment: @AnT, проверил в другом компиляторе и это работает...