# Запись и чтение бинарного файла (C++)

Tags: c++, io, binary, binary-file

Нужно записывать в файл информацию о машинах, и иметь возможность этот файл дополнить и прочитать определенное количество записей. При чтении из бинарного файла выводится следующее:

```
    Automobile 1�犎�
                    Brand: dasf0�t�UMileage: asdf芎�
                Price: asdf 芎�
                               Automobile 2�犎�Brand: afdsfdas0�t�U`�t�UMileage: dafs芎�
                Price: fdas
```

(Прошу прощения за бессмысленный набор букв в значениях полей). Я так понимаю, как-то неправильно интерпретируется эскейп последовательность перехода на новую строку. Для записи использую вот такую функцию:

```
void binary_write(std::ofstream& ofs, std::string& s){                                                             
     ofs.write((char*)&s, sizeof(s));                                                                               
 }
```

Вот строки, которые пишу:

```
first_line = "Automobile " + std::to_string(count+1);                                                      
         brand = "Brand: " + brand;                                                                                 
         manufacture = "Manufacture: " + manufacture;                                                               
         release = "Year of release: " + release;                                                                   
         mileage = "Mileage: " + mileage;                                                                           
         price = "Price: " + price;
```

Код чтения:

```
while(ifs.read(&temp, sizeof(char)))                                                               
                       std::cout << temp;
```

Может кто-нибудь подсказать, как корректно организовать ввод-вывод используя бинарные файлы?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если вам не принципиален какой-то собственный бинарный формат, быстрее и удобнее взять какую-нибудь библиотеку json (например https://github.com/nlohmann/json) где уже все готово для чтения/записи строк, массивов, словарей и др.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы посмотрите на размер sizeof(std::string), то обнаружите, что он или 24, или 32 (в зависимости от версии компилятора, но не длины строки). А все потому, что string - это на самом деле класс, который хранит размер, указатель и емкость. Но если строка маленькая (обычно это символов 15), то данные хранятся прям внутри (именно поэтому Вы и видите какие то строки).

Как правильно писать строки? есть два способа. Первый - писать, ограничив нулевым символом. Это просто.

```
void binary_write(std::ofstream& ofs, std::string& s){                                                             
     ofs.write(s.c_str(), s.length()+1);                                                                               
 }
```

(тут выглядит как будто есть выход за границы, но его нет).

А вот с чтением такого чуточку сложнее - придется читать по символьно, пока ноль не найдется.

Второй способ - вначале писать размер строки, а потом саму строку. Понятно, что при чтении можно длину прочитать и выделить буфер нужного размера + прочитать эту самую строку.

Вот например, посмотрите на этот ответ [Запись и чтение объекта из бинарного файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980142/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0?rq=1)

Comment: Большое вам спасибо